# Create a team... lots of Typos

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams, spelling

Losely...
Indivduals...
Porpose...

[image]

Comment: we got to excite

Comment: So purpose or porpoise? Because a team of dolphins would be pretty awesome. I'd upvote it.

Comment: @theB it's not a team of dolphins... it's the team's dolphin. So... we need to  describe our team mascot, which HAS to be a porpoise?

Comment: Excuse me, are you proposing to discriminate against aquatic developers?

Comment: @Patrice - So [this](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/424328093621178368/c_eX48-0.jpeg) then? Or [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_Kms07DaCrcc/TN6x8HWorYI/AAAAAAAAAQo/fWWpCOWTPHQ/s1600/Uni_luvs_Dolphi___TD_Style_by_Cazantyl-1.png)?

Comment: What's the porpoise of your assocetacean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well...that's embarrassing. Normally this is caught with the translations but we're skipping that step for the small beta - fixed in a build deploying shortly.