# How do I create a team?

Tags: support, old-teams

I was directed to the [teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) page and I couldn't find my team. How do I create my team?

[Others  seem to have found such an entry point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309719/create-a-team-lots-of-typos) with lots oy typos. I don't care about the typos. Where is it?

Comment: I get a "Create Team" button at the top. [Ref](http://i.imgur.com/M7TAUhm.png)

Comment: I think [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308477/4099593) might solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but were you picked to participate in the Beta program?

Comment: @Oldskool: it seems not. But I can participate in other SE sites that are in beta state (like [sqa](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/)) without requesting an invitation and without being selected.

Comment: @BhargavRao: you can add the screenshot as an answer, if you like. I'd not like to close it as duplicate of the linked answer, since the position and availability of the button in the screenshot provides additional value.

Comment: @Thomas Beta sites in the SE network are something else entirely. They are open to all, but just not permanent yet. Beta features are closed to a selected group of people.

Comment: If you have a good team idea, I could create a team for you and invite you (you’d have full permissions then). Just find me on chat.

Comment: @poke: I have invited myself for the beta via a Google forms submission (linked in the answer). I had to give the team a name. Waiting for a confirmation email now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Thomas Orozco's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308477/4099593) the creation of teams is allowed only for those who have signed up for the [private beta](http://goo.gl/forms/nosBAAcbvG) as mentioned in this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307513/4099593). In his own words :

> In the beta phase, ***creating teams will be limited to beta members***

Once you have registered for the private beta, you will get a <kbd>Create Team</kbd> button. Attached is a screenshot for your reference.

[image: Create Team]