# Is Teams Beta still open?

Tags: support, old-teams

I registered to create a new Team on Feb 9, but I haven't received any kind of notification or feedback and I'm still unable to create a team from the [Teams page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams). Is it still open to new participants? Are we still using [this form](https://docs.google.com/a/skuidify.com/forms/d/1xhfLWQMysn-fYX7ucYik7b1jPIpdg90O4CoNECKyZm0/viewform?c=0&w=1) to register?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/teams ? It launched [back in November](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309716/the-teams-private-beta-is-starting).

Comment: @meagar - Then how do I create a team?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Team creation is still in private beta I think, and it's possible that they aren't pulling new people in yet.

Comment: See [How do I create a team?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310465)

Comment: @BhargavRao - I followed those steps on Feb 9.

Comment: @JDB Then go to http://stackoverflow.com/teams. Can you see Create Team button?

Comment: @BhargavRao - Updated question. No... I registered, but I've not yet been added to the beta.

Comment: For the secondary question, "is Teams still active?": the two most [recent proposals](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316135/what-do-we-want-out-of-teams-and-how-could-we-make-it-work?lq=1) where both [in Feb](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316245/what-team-member-so-activity-should-we-gather-and-show-on-teams?lq=1) so there is likely still some active development (or at least re-design)

Comment: @jgreen - I didn't actually ask if teams is active, because [it clearly is](http://stackoverflow.com/teams). I asked if they were still accepting users into the beta.

Comment: should have said "*a* secondary question" - I just wanted these questions linked as the most recent discussions of Teams. As I, at least, had some trouble finding the second one

Answer (score 4):

It probably was at the time you asked the question.

As the private beta continued, at August 2nd, 2016  it was anounced that [Teams would un-ship](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/the-un-shipping-of-teams) and in the 9th of that same month it was [status completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332020/578411).

We'll never know the real reason why your team didn't make it ...

Comment: Actually, I got my team. Thanks for the update.