# The Un-shipping of Teams

Tags: discussion, status-completed, old-teams

For almost the past year, we've had [Teams in private beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) and while we believe in its potential value, after a lot of consideration we've decided to un-ship the idea for the time being.

> [image: unshipping]

Teams will shut down in about a week, meaning you will no longer be able to access, join, or create new ones.  A single data dump of the existing Teams will be available on the [landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) once we’ve disbanded all the teams.

It has become clear that making a successful version of the [Team page, as we originally proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions) would ultimately take more time and resources than we want to devote to it.  Our developer resources are currently allocated on various projects to enhance and improve quality on Q&A, Documentation, and Jobs on Stack Overflow, as a result we don’t have the dedicated developers to get Teams to its fullest potential.

Teams was part of our plan to [serve programmers better](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better), and it was created as a way for groups of users to share info about themselves. This included professional teams, open-source projects, and even internal Stack Overflow groups working towards a common goal.  Our intention was to add more features to Teams, but we never expanded it to anything beyond a team description.

For those interested, we currently have **295 teams** and 8 of those teams have more than 50 users.

Thanks again to all the users who participated in Teams!  We’ll hopefully re-ship this again in the next [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)!

Comment: I hope this isn't because you guys' tolerance for grief from the community for unpopular (or rather, much criticized) ideas has started to wear out - and that it doesn't mean Team is on the shelf permanently, as it really seemed like an idea with potential. Sometimes, the community's reflexive rejection of all things "social" tends to throw the baby out with the bathwater - yes, it is a *good* thing to get to know other developers and what they do. It doesn't automatically mean the place has to turn into a social network where people share trivial silliness.

Comment: I wonder if it has also been triggered by the recent misuse of it (you know, the anti-docs team…) … But I agree in general, teams is quite disappointing as of what's possible with it now [as @Pekka웃 notes correctly, it has some potential, but current state :-/] and documentation is a far more important topic currently.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Not at all, we really believe there is potential for Teams but as I mentioned we don't have the resources to bring it to fruition at this time, so instead of leaving it out there without much happening, it makes more sense to un-ship to a later date.

Comment: @Pekka웃 We simply felt it was time to find _new and better_ ways to test our tolerance for grief from the community.

Comment: @Ana so we're finally going to get that private messaging feature? And mandatory comments on downvotes? Yay!

Comment: @Pekka웃 There are plenty of good parts of teams that we'll definitely keep in mind as we look at more _specific_ ways that association with something is both desired and useful for users. I think we took a lot of good ideas and rolled them out into a big feature called 'teams', but maybe we should have been looking at a few different features. The idea isn't lost, but there's no 'fits all cases' implementation.

Comment: +35/-0?  I know voting on meta is different but are we all that happy that it get removed? Have a down vote, to compensate. :(

Comment: @rene "*This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear*" :( ;)

Comment: +1 for effective use of GIFs. -1 for sadness.

Comment: Bummer. I'm a fan of the feature and I'm sad to see it go away. If/when it returns, will the existing teams be intact?

Comment: Feel free to take any and all resources away from Documentation to save Teams.

Comment: @m69 So you think it's OK to leave docs in it's current state? Awesome, let's remove the beta tag right now and ship it.

Comment: Great, now un-ship Documentation too and we'll be fine!

Comment: @m69 we used the wrong approach with teams and we ended up with a huge chicken-and-egg problem, so we need to `git reset --hard`. Some of the problems worth solving (i.e. allowing users to group over "things") are certainly something we are working on without pause and a different solution will be available soon.

Comment: The best part is realizing what priorities are and whether efforts are worth building something. A lot of teams(and managers/product owners) failed to do so

Comment: @Sklivvz you've got a diamond and are communicating SO news like a human instead of a PR rep! Thanks :-)

Comment: [renaming of Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-site-name) took too much resources I think

Answer (score 32):

[Teams have been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) in build rev 2016.8.9.3873 - long live teams!

[image: cat going backwards]

Comment: RIP Teams! We all will wait for 6-8 weeks before you rise again.

Comment: Is this 6-8 weeks the same timeframe that we should expect chat flags to be fixed? ;)

Comment: You may should link to this question in the team page I was searching for this question for some minutes.