# Where does Stack Overflow get a real name from?

Tags: support, developer-story, stack-overflow-jobs

I have just had a job email and message via Stack Overflow. Both used a real name rather than my screen name, and I do not remember entering this, nor can I find where this is shown on Stack Overflow.

However the issue is that the name is wrong (I have legally changed my name over a year ago). While I am not that unhappy about a real name being available, changing it to be correct is VERY important to me.

How can this be changed, or where is it incorrectly dragging it from to change there?

Comment: There's a 'full name' option at the bottom of the Edit profile page: http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1723545

Comment: @Glorfindel - thank you, but that actually does show my updated real name rather than the one shown on the jobs email and message

Comment: @Kickstart do you have a Developer Story? http://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1723545 or an old jobs profile you may have imported from a CV? If you do - then look at the right hand side column nnear the bottom and you'll see a "Full Name" which'll enable you to then edit another "Full Name" which is for employers/the jobs system rather than the "Real Name" used on Q&A...

Comment: @JonClements - Thank you. It seems it had picked it up from a CV at some point. Pity it is fairly well hidden!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - emailed you, be interesting to know which names have shown up where.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've already found and edited this thanks to Jon Clements' comment, but for anyone else confused by this... There are currently *four* places where a name can be attached to your profile:

1. Your Display Name is what's shown on your profile and anything you post on the site, and can be changed by editing the Public Information section of your profile.
2. Your Full Name is used only in private emails and can be changed by editing the Private Information section of your profile.
3. Your Developer Story Display Name is what's shown to folks casually browsing Stack Overflow who come across your Developer Story (if it is public). This *can* be synchronized with your normal Display Name, but otherwise is changed by editing the top section on your Developer Story.
4. Your Developer Story Full Name is what's shown to employers or others if your developer story is private but shared through a custom URL. This can also be synchronized with your normal Full Name, but otherwise is changed by editing the top section of your Developer Story.

Name #4 was out of sync for you, presumably because it was imported from an old Careers CV and thus reflected the name at the time *that* was created.

Comment: Thank you. I can't remember uploading a CV but I might have done at some point. Can't see a specific source of the CV to make sure it is deleted.

Comment: The CV data is currently archived (will be removed entirely in the near future); you can re-import it using the link on the sidebar of your story (overwriting your story), but otherwise you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have an up to date CV (major things going on in my life so not job hunting).

Comment: The bad part about this is its TOO many options.  Its the same thing with the jobs site.  Our company name is wrong..If I update in one place it doesn't update ALL the other places.  I have placed meta issues about it and directly emailed SO and get no where with it.  Why is the db design so effed up?

Comment: I agree, @JonH. Long-term - and hopefully not *that* long-term - there should be much less redundancy between "Story" and "profile", much less of a wall between the two, and much more flexibility in saying, "this bit of my personal life gets shown to ONLY these people"; same with company information, group affiliation, etc. - that's what we were originally going for with Teams, but kinda bit off more than we could chew there.

Comment: Teams...whatever happened to that?  I totally forgot about it. I can imagine teams may help you guys with security down the road.  Maybe certain "teams" see certain things.  Then you can right code like `if(isAdmin || Teams.IsUserInTeam(TeamsEnum.CSharp))`

Comment: Yeah, well, that was kinda the problem - in theory, such a feature could be useful for TONS of stuff: imagine a "PHP mentoring team" or a "regex answer moderation committee" (motto: "now we have M^2 problems"). Besides the obvious "let folks who work together fix the spelling of their company name" stuff. But... We didn't quite know *what* we were building it for, so [it ended up not really working well for anything](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/the-un-shipping-of-teams) and was shelved; chances are, we'll end up with something similar, but built to serve specific goals. @Jon

Comment: @Shog9 - Give it a few years I think you guys will make use of it.  We are using "teams" for an internal site I am developing and it has helped us out tremendously.