# Allow Q&A on company pages

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

For the jobs section of SO I am looking to have a way to allow Q&A within a company page.  For instance, I may read about company Acme and wonder about various topics about this company or even the roles at this company.  I may very well want to ask:

> Are remote days allowed once in a while?
>
> What is the interview process like?
>
> What are the expected hours like?
>
> What activities if any outside of work do you guys get involved with?
>
> Are there charities you guys help out with?
>
> What is my typical day going to look like?
>
> Is lunch 1/2 hour an hour or more?

The question could be answered by people who work at the company or the company that placed the page up.  You already have a page for employers who can respond to candidates - so open this up to allow answering questions directly from potential people looking to work here.  These questions should allow public view with no user details presented (anon post only) so that anyone can get an understanding of how a company is.

Answer (score -10):

Thank you for this suggestion as well.

I am told that a similar feature was, at one time, on the roadmap for the now-defunct [Teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/the-un-shipping-of-teams) project.  We could certainly envision a feature that facilitates questions and answers (both anonymous) as part of an employer's curated Company Page.  This type of interaction between developers and employers could help employers with their branding on the site.

As with every good idea, it's a matter of when it will get high enough on the priority list for anyone to work on it.  This one would likely go to the Talent team (think the employer-facing side of Jobs) for implementation.  I know it's not on their immediate roadmap, so I'll mark this one [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now.